# Is there a way to access OpenWhisk logs from the API?

Tags: openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

I want to programatically dump logs from OpenWhisk in to an external service. I can do this by capturing log output and then posting it at the end of every action but this adds overhead to my function.

Is there a way to get this data from the OpenWhisk API similar to `wsk activation logs ACTIVATION_ID`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action logs are available through the [platform API](http://petstore.swagger.io/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/master/core/controller/src/main/resources/apiv1swagger.json). Console output from actions (`stdout` or `stderr`) is stored in the activation records.

Activation records can be accessed by sending a HTTP request to the following endpoint:
`/namespaces/{namespace}/activations/{activationid}/logs`

Client libraries for accessing the API are available for [multiple](https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-client-js) [languages](https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-client-go).